# How to recognize a lot of objects and add a lot of nodes at the same time?

Tags: ios, swift, augmented-reality, scenekit, arkit

This is the simple object when I use for `ARImageTrackingConfiguration()`.

[image]

Within code I add a plane and paperPlane onto recognized object:

```swift
    func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, nodeFor anchor: ARAnchor) -> SCNNode? {
        let node = SCNNode()
        if let imageAnchor = anchor as? ARImageAnchor {
            let plane = SCNPlane(width: imageAnchor.referenceImage.physicalSize.width, 
                                height: imageAnchor.referenceImage.physicalSize.height)
            plane.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.green.withAlphaComponent(0.8)
            let planeNode = SCNNode(geometry: plane)
            planeNode.eulerAngles.x = -.pi / 2
            planeNode.position.y = 0
            let paperPlaneScene = SCNScene(named: "Scenes.scnassets/paperPlane.scn")!
            let paperPlaneNode = paperPlaneScene.rootNode.childNodes.first!
            paperPlaneNode.position = SCNVector3Zero
            paperPlaneNode.position.z = 0.1
            paperPlaneNode.eulerAngles.y = -.pi / 2
            paperPlaneNode.eulerAngles.z = .pi
            planeNode.addChildNode(paperPlaneNode)
            node.addChildNode(planeNode)
        }
        return node
    }
```

But the result is following:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Why there is only one recognized object at time? And not every of them? They are recognized one by one, but never all at once. Why?

Answer (score 0):

In the latest version of ARKit 5.0 you can [simultaneously](https://developer.apple.com/augmented-reality/arkit/) detect up to 100 images using such classes as ARImageTrackingConfiguration or ARWorldTrackingConfiguration.

To detect up to 100 images at a time use the following instance property:

```
var maximumNumberOfTrackedImages: Int { get set }
```

In a real code it looks like this:

```
guard let reference = ARReferenceImage.referenceImages(inGroupNamed: "ARRes", 
                                                             bundle: nil) 
else { fatalError("Missing resources") }

let config = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
config.maximumNumberOfTrackedImages = 10
config.detectionImages = reference

arView.session.run(config, options: [.resetTracking, .removeExistingAnchors])
```

And here's an extension with `renderer(_:didAdd:for:)` instance method:

```
extension ViewController: ARSCNViewDelegate {

    func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer,
                 didAdd node: SCNNode,
                  for anchor: ARAnchor) {

        guard let imageAnchor = anchor as? ARImageAnchor,
              let imageName = imageAnchor.referenceImage.name
        else { return }

        let geometryNode = nodeGetter(name: imageName)
        node.addChildNode(geometryNode)
    }

    func nodeGetter(name: String) -> SCNNode {

        var node = SCNNode()

        switch name {
            case "geometry_01": node = modelOne
            case "geometry_02": node = modelTwo
            case "geometry_03": node = modelThree
            case "geometry_04": node = modelFour
            case "geometry_05": node = modelFive
            case "geometry_06": node = modelSix
            case "geometry_07": node = modelSeven
            case "geometry_08": node = modelEight
            default: break
        }
        return node
    }
}
```